# How do I pass a simple (enumeration) parameter into a class in C#?

Tags: c#, class, parameters, enumeration

```
class Person //I'm want to pass the parameter "Gender"
{
    public string firstName;
    public string lastName;
    public int age;
    //public string gender;
```

This is a piece of code that I'm working with. I'm new to programming, and I'm working with C#. I have an enumeration called "Gender" it consists of "Male" and "Female". I have a class called "Person" and I want to pass a parameter telling the system that each new "Person" MUST have a gender, male or female. I'm pretty sure I'm supposed to pass the parameter near the top close to the class.

Comment: Google for `enum`. They work as in C/C++

Comment: Not a very inclusive system you're programming there.

Comment: tom.dietrich makes a good point... today the question of sex is complicated, specially in the western world (today the news was that Germany no longer requires to register the sex of the newborns, in case there is some doubt).

Answer (score 2):

> I want to pass a parameter telling the system that each new `Person` MUST have a gender

You enforce that through the constructor:

```
public class Person //I'm want to pass the parameter "Gender"
{
    public string firstName;
    public string lastName;
    public int age;
    public Gender gender;  // recommend storing the enum instead of a string

    public Person (Gender gender)
    {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
}
```

Implementing a constructor with a parameter removes the "default" constructor, so anyone that creates a `Person` *must* supply a gender.

I's also recommend using *properties* instead of *fields* but that's a separate issue...

Answer (score 1):

First, you can easily just add a new member for the person's Gender with a type of Gender (which is, I assume, the name of the enum):

```
public Gender Gender;
```

Since you want to force that a person must have a specific gender upon the object's creation you need to stipulate that in the class's *constructor*:

```
public Person(Gender PersonGender)
{
   Gender = PersonGender;
}
```

So your class becomes something like this:

```
class Person
{
    public string firstName;
    public string lastName;
    public int age;
    public Gender Gender;

    public Person(Gender PersonGender)
    {
       Gender = PersonGender;
    }
}
```

Note that in C#, unlike in C/C++, it doesn't really matter where you *put* the methods and the members. Just keep them organized for ease of reading.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Person
{
    public string firstName;
    public string lastName;
    public int age;
    public Gender Gender;
}
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx) for more information on `enum` types in C#.